# Identifying Modes

Tags: theory, modes

I'm getting introduced to modes and got a small homework assignment to identify the modes of some short melodies. The problem is I'm not sure that I'm following the guideline correctly, and I can't ask my teacher because he's currently on a leave and I have to upload the solution to the school's website.
[image]

I solved it as if the last note, B flat, was the "root" of the mode and find its relations with the other notes, which would mean the first melody (I think) is in Dorian mode. Am I doing it correctly? In general does "do" represent the root/tonic of a scale or a mode?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it 100% correctly, yep!

"Do" is just a solfége term for tonic, so in this case this is a B-flat mode. Since we have `Df` and `Af`, we're looking at B-flat Dorian.

Comment: I was taught that "Do" corresponds to the C note and it's not just a term for tonic.

Comment: There are basically two systems. In *fixed* systems, "do" is always C. In *movable* systems, "do" is always the tonic.

Comment: ok that makes sense wasnt aware of the movable system

Comment: There's Bb and Eb in there too, making the parent key Ab, (four flats)  thus Bb Dorian. But I guess with Ab and Db in there, these two are a given.

Answer (score 0):

It's in Dorian correct. The G note gives it away.

here are the degrees also.

Bflat(TONIC)
C(SUPERTONIC)
Dflat(MEDIANT)
Eflat(SUBDOMINANT)
F(DOMINANT)
G(SUBMEDIANT)
Aflat(LEADING TONE)

Comment: How does the G note give it away?

Comment: Presumably because Gf would mean it was just natural minor/Aeolian.

Comment: Only insofar as 6 rises to ♭7. ♭6 was standard _ficta_ for Dorian mode.